# Spring batch default transaction function not working for stored procedure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have writer simple batch job with the reader-processor configuration in spring batch. In processor I calling stored procedure for some DB updates,
normal flow is working fine but whenever some exception occurring after executing the stored procedure the update records are not rollbacked.

@Configuration
public class StudentJobConfig {

```
@Bean
ItemReader<Student> studentReader() {
    // reads data from database
}

@Bean
ItemProcessor<Student, Student> studentProcessor() {
    // execute the stored procedure 
}


@Bean
Step studentStep(ItemReader<Student> studentReader,
                         ItemProcessor<Student, Student> studentProcessor,
                         StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("StudentStep")
            .<Student, Student>chunk(1)
            .reader(studentReader)
            .processor(studentProcessor)
            .build();
}

@Bean
Job inMemoryStudentJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                       @Qualifier("studentStep") Step studentStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("StudentJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(studentStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

}

Comment: Add more code for the stored procedure. Add the exception stack trace. You can save only one Student in each processor iteration. Maybe better store student collection in the writer?

Comment: Please share your transaction manager configuration.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I using the default spring batch transaction manager configuration

Comment: The default transaction manager is a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`. It does not commit or rollback any transaction. That's your issue. You need to configure a `DatasourceTransactionManager` pointing to the datasource your stored procedure is executed against.